# I got error ‘403 Forbidden Access is forbidden to the requested page’

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Dear forum members,

I have the error:

'403 Forbidden

Access is forbidden to the requested page: www.goldenprincess.fr/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fgoldenprincess.fr%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 (port 80) '

This happens when I try to connect to the wordpress admin page. Then I click "Enter" and re-enter the URL and dont have this error anymore (cookies placed).

Why I have it and what should I do to solve it.

thank you very much in advance,

Comment: This is not a programming question. You'd be better off asking this on the WordPress forums.

Comment: Not relevant to the programming...

Comment: Use a MySQL string replace to fix your link to match your site URL. It looks like you migrated without fully updating URLs in your DB. Example https://wpbeaches.com/updating-wordpress-mysql-database-after-moving-to-a-new-url/

Comment: I did not migrate, it was a clean instal. That i s why I dont understand why I have this redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is normal for WordPress to encode the redirect URL in the query string like that but it gives you a 403, there is most likely some security on the server (e.g. [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/)) that is configured to block requests like that since it is probably being mistaken for some kind of attack.

If you have the ability to change those rules or contact your host to do so, it will be necessary unless you are okay with manually removing that portion from the URL each time you want to log in.